# Difference between SimpleDateFormat and strtotime?

Tags: java, php, date-format

What is the difference between this in PHP

```
echo strtotime("2013-08-30");
```

and this in Java

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = sdf.parse("2013-08-30");
System.out.println(date.getTime());
```

Shouldn't this give me the same number in the end?

**EDIT**

For example in this case the PHP gives:
1377838800

And Java gives: 1377838800000

Its like PHP loses a few zeroes somewhere along the way

Comment: What does the documentation of each method tell you?

Comment: Instead of `strtotime()` you should use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). Like `SimpleDateFormat` it accepts custom formats + timezone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PHP strtotime()**

- Parse about any English textual datetime description into a **Unix timestamp**

Unix timestamp:

- the number of **seconds** since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC

This

```
echo strtotime("2013-08-30");
```

will return `1377835200`

---

**Java Date.getTime()**

- Returns the number of **milliseconds** since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object.

This

```
System.out.println(date.getTime());
```

will return `1377831600000`.

Which means you should perform

```
System.out.println(date.getTime() / 1000);
```

Also, in case of discrepancies, check your timezones.

Comment: That explains the losing zeroes problem

Comment: @beenjaminnn No zeroes were lost during the process, they're just in a different format. it's like 10000000 => 989680... DAMN, where did all my zeroes went? NOWHERE! the first is decimal, the second is hexadecimal. 1000 = 1k. same story.

Answer (score 2):

No. As documented, [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) returns the **seconds** since the Unix epoch; [`Date.getTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) returns the **milliseconds** since the Unix epoch.

Additionally, you may notice differences in the default time zones used by Java and PHP. (You can set the time zone of a `SimpleDateFormat` if you want to use a specific one.)

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Java, but the `strtotime()` function in PHP is exceptionally adept at understanding a date written in pretty much any format that makes sense and returns a date object. I would assume that Java is much more stringent about what inputs you can enter to get the desired result.

From the PHP docs (http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) on strtotime:

```
<?php
echo strtotime("now"), "\n";
echo strtotime("10 September 2000"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 day"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 week"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 week 2 days 4 hours 2 seconds"), "\n";
echo strtotime("next Thursday"), "\n";
echo strtotime("last Monday"), "\n";
?>
```

All these are much more will return a valid date.